# How to print Cyrillic PDF in C#? Text missing

Tags: c#, printing, itext

I use iTextSharp to create document in my programs. All text in documents is Russian, I use Tahoma fonts:

```
    private static void PrepareFonts()
    {
        _baseTahoma = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:/windows/fonts/tahoma.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        _tahomaBold = new Font(_baseTahoma, 10, Font.BOLD);
        _tahoma = new Font(_baseTahoma, 10, Font.NORMAL);
        _tahoma16Bold = new Font(_baseTahoma, 18, Font.BOLD);
        _tahomaSmall = new Font(_baseTahoma, 8, Font.NORMAL);
    }
```

When document is created, I print it on button click that way:

```
        RegistryKey adobe = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\AcroRd32.exe");

        if (adobe != null)
        {
            string path = adobe.GetValue("").ToString();

            GenerateDocuments();

            Process proc = new Process();

            proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            proc.StartInfo.Verb = "print";

            string pdfFileName = _invoice.FullName;

            proc.StartInfo.FileName = path;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/p /h " + pdfFileName;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            proc.Start();
            proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            if (proc.HasExited == false)
            {
                if (!proc.WaitForExit(5000))
                    proc.Kill();
            }

            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            proc.Close();
        }
```

But on the paper there are only lines from tables without any characters. There's no text or numbers.

In requirements specification is written that user must print documents on button click and I have to do it that way. Manual opening document and "Print as image" are not possible.

Can anyone give suggestion, how can I print Cyrillic document?

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting something, but why are you executing Acrobat Reader? It looks like the second piece of code is absolutely irrelevant to your problem. What's in the `GenerateDocuments` function?

Comment: @J0HN GenerateDocuments - it's method create PDF documents. Font defining (1st listing) is from that method.

Comment: Ok, I think contents of `GenerateDocuments` are much more relevant than your second code sample. Could you please update your question adding `GenerateMethod` listing?

Comment: Big listing: http://pastebin.com/L2yCRAQN
First part - method GenerateDocuments. It calls creation of Act and Invoice.
Second part - code of generation Invoice.

Comment: Well, I believe if you try to simplify your code and come up with a much shorter sample that reproduce your problem it's either you will find the solution as a byproduct of simplification or somebody will be able to find it for you. At the moment that huge code listing just makes it almost impossible to find the root cause.

Comment: It's not necessary to review all of my code in big listing. I believe there is a problem in Encoding that iTextSharp setting for document or  in incorrect way to printing. I deliberately posted only 2 small listings for question.

Comment: It might be a better approach if you supplied a sample PDF you observed the behavior with.

Comment: @mkl Sample PDF here: http://ge.tt/2WCRmpS/v/0

Comment: @Drac I'm not in office anymore, but the PDF looks correct in my cellular phone, so the font information send to be there. I'll look into printing it in office tomorrow.

Comment: The problem can't be reproduced. When printed, I see Latin and Cyrillic glyphs. There is one major mistake in the code though: only tahoma.ttf is registered, which is the regular font. If you need Bold glyphs, you also need to register tahomabd.ttf.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie did you print with option "Print as image" enabled? With code `new Font(_baseTahoma, 10, Font.BOLD)` I define style `Font.BOLD` and it's not necessary to use `tahomabd.ttf`.

Comment: Why would you 'Print as image'? That's also known as 'degraded printing'. Degraded = less quality.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I agree, but I don't understand why you cannot reproduce error... I use "Print as image" sometimes, when I cannot print document correctly.

Comment: @Drac Concerning "With code new Font(_baseTahoma, 10, Font.BOLD) I define style Font.BOLD and it's not necessary to use tahomabd.ttf" --- there is a difference between those two: Your bold essentially uses the non-bold version and prints a thicker borderline, while a basefont tahomabd.ttf without additional styles would use the actual Tahoma bold glyphs which can be expected to look (slightly) better.

Comment: On the printing subject I can only repeat @BrunoLowagie's words "The problem can't be reproduced." But if "Print as image" sometimes resolved printing issues for you, that sounds like your printer driver or printer firmware has dire deficiencies which very well could be the reason for the problem at hand here.

Comment: It's really hard to update our drivers cause another department do this. I'll try to find another way of printing.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Drac When I open the file, I see Cyrillic characters; when I print the file (normal printing), I see Cyrillic characters. If some printer isn't able to print the document correctly, you need to look at your printer driver (maybe you're using the wrong one) or your printer.